# ApolloError: forward is not a function in nextjs

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

I'm not sure how to fix this ApolloError: forward is not a function
issue.

I've tried adding an error code as per the documentation nothing is working

please help!

apollo.client.ts

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client'
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';

const API_URL = process.env.WORDPRESS_API_URL
const errorLink = onError(
  ({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors)
          graphQLErrors.forEach(
              ({ message, locations, path }) =>
                  console.log(
                      `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location:           ${JSON.stringify(locations)}, Path: ${JSON.stringify(path)}`
                   )
          );
      if (networkError) {
          console.log(`[Network error]: ${JSON.stringify(networkError)}`);
      }
  }
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: API_URL, 
  link: errorLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})

export default client
```

Answer (score 0):

The moment you use `link`, you can't use `url` anymore - it will be ignored. So instead of having a `HttpLink` before, you now only have a `ErrorLink` with no network layer behind it.

This is what you need to do:

```js
const errorLink = onError(/* .... */)
const httpLink = new HttpLink({ 

const client = new ApolloClient({ uri: API_URL })
  link: errorLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```